# Questions about QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

If I make a QThread and call one of its slots from another thread, will it be called in the context of the thread of the QThread object, or from the context of the thread which made the call?

Answer (score 4):

If you execute the slot by emitting a signal, then it depends on the type of signal-to-slot connection you have. A slot connected to a signal via a direct connection would execute in the emitter's thread. A slot connected via a queued connection would execute in the receiver's thread. Please see here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qobject.html

If the slot is executed directly, with [QThread object]->slot(), then the slot will execute in the thread that makes the call.

Comment: Actually now that I read the documentation more carefully, it says: "Like other objects, QThread objects live in the thread where the object was created -- not in the thread that is created when QThread::run() is called. It is generally unsafe to provide slots in your QThread subclass, unless you protect the member variables with a mutex." 

So what would happen is that the slot would be handled in the main thread, because the QThread object itself lives there. Even if I called the slot from the worker thread, it would be queued to be processed in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Direct calls are always executed in the context of the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

A slot called by a signal will run in the thread for which the `QObject` is associated. A slot called directly will run in the current thread. Here is a test program which demonstrates.

Output:

```
main() thread: QThread(0x804d470)
run() thread: Thread(0xbff7ed94)
onRunning() direct call; thread: Thread(0xbff7ed94)
onRunning() signaled; thread: QThread(0x804d470)
```

Test program:

```
#include <QtCore>

class Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    void run()
    {
        qDebug() << "run() thread:" << QThread::currentThread();
        emit running();
    }

public slots:
    void onRunning()
    {
        qDebug() << "onRunning() thread:" << QThread::currentThread();
    }

signals:
    void running();
};

#include "threadTest.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "main() thread:" << QThread::currentThread();

    Thread t;
    QObject::connect(&t, SIGNAL(running()), &t, SLOT(onRunning()));
    t.start();

    QTimer::singleShot(100, &app, SLOT(quit()));

    return app.exec();
}
```